# Retag closed questions?

Tags: support, tags

I've been cleaning up some tag errors and have discovered that there is no easy way to retag a closed question. There should be. Can this be added?

In particular, I was trying to retag "opensource" to "open-source"

Comment: If this existed it'd be easier to get rid of the "belongs-on-*" tags

Comment: I seem to be able to edit closed questions. Perhaps it's a reputation-based capability?

Comment: D'oh - I was thinking of migrated questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855128/stackoverflow-website-code-downloadable-or-free-to-use-closed)? Locked questions (such as due to migration) cannot be edited, including tags. But they are *not* immune to global retags by ♦ moderators, and that *also* has the advantage of not spamming the front page.

Since there were 23 opensource and >1300 open-source, I'll merge into open-source for you:

```
updating post history, 23 rows affected
updating posts, 20 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
merge of [open-source] and [opensource] complete!
```

Better?

Comment: Cool. Can you do the same for this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servlet It should be retagged `Servlets`.

Answer (score 1):

I've only noticed not being able to retag closed items when they've been migrated. Migrated items are locked, meaning they cannot be edited in any way.

Retagging, even of closed items, is not rep-based. On SU, I have ~1200 rep (not enough to edit, but enough to retag). I was able to retag [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1542/which-is-the-best-free-antivirus-for-a-home-pc) successfully.

So the question is: Were you trying to retag a question which was closed due to migration? (You'll see a message at the bottom of the question indicating such.)